# Need help with Cache::invalidateTags() and cacheable metadata in REST route

Tags: 8, caching

I have a REST route that returns some JSON. I am trying to get cache tags working correct, but it doesn't seem to be working. Only updates if I flush all cache.

I have a queue that runs on cron every hour and it just pulls from a third party API. Within my queue, I check that the data being sent over contains a `winner` value. If it does, I set that value on the node and then I also want to invalidate the cache for my REST route.

Within my queue:

```php
if (isset($data['winner'])) {
  Cache::invalidateTags(['tournament_is_complete']); // Invalidate the cache here
  $winningPlayer = self::upsertPlayer($data['winner']);
  $tournament->set('field_winner', ['target_id' => $winningPlayer->id()]);
}
$tournament->save();
```

In my REST route I have this GET function defined with my cacheable metadata set.

```php
public function get($gid) {
  $cacheable_metadata = CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray([
    '#cache' => [
      'tags' => [
        'tournament_is_complete',
      ],
    ],
  ]);

  // Get group.
  $group = Group::load($gid);

  .....
  Does a bunch of stuff
  .....
  
  // Return the results.
  $payload = [
    'gid' => $gid,
    'message' => 'success',
    'headers' => $header,
    'rows' => $this->leaderboard,
  ];
  return (new ResourceResponse($payload))->addCacheableDependency($cacheable_metadata);
}
```

I thought that would be enough for the cache to be reset on this route, but its not (still shows old data). If I flush drupal cache then it loads in the new data.

EDIT: Forgot to mention my rest route is being called within a block. Perhaps its the block itself being cached?

The custom block

```php
public function build() {
  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
    $build['message'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => 'Access denied.',
    ];
    return $build;
  }

  // Table rendered in JS.
  $build['content'] = [
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<table class="leaderboard-table table"><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table><div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><div class="spinner-border text-primary"><span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span></div></div>',
  ];
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the response of your REST route directly and not just look at the block rendered output?

Comment: Try adding the tag to the block as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was waiting until my 3rd party data updated on their end. I made sure to check the JSON response first before clearing the cache and its still cached. I see my node now has a winner set so `Cache::invalidateTags(['tournament_is_complete']);` was for sure called. @Kevin

Comment: @Jaypan I have added this cache tag to my block as well, but when viewing my rest route directly, the data coming from the REST route is still cached.